# Firebug CSS strike-through

Tags: css, firebug, strikethrough

I've made an global css that I used in two page (basic search and advance search page). I use it in advance search page, and the css script is running well. But when I move to basic search page (by click a link), the css not working. I used firebug to see what happen, and then I found that the css script is strike-through.
[image: css strike-through]
How can I solve it,.?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That basically means that your CSS property is being overriden by another CSS.

See where that property is defined, and you'll probably need to fix the order of the CSS inclusion on your web-page.

Comment: do you mean that `input.range` is used by another CSS,.?

Comment: Maybe, or another selector that matches that same input, like the class or ID. The property you defined is "width", if you look at your firebug window, there's a "width" property defined right above it, with 180px. You should be able to figure out where it's coming from.

Comment: thank's for your clue, now it's work well, I've disable the rule that overide `input.range` rule. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad it helps =) You can accept the answer if your problem is now solved.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I need to use this convention for displaying overridden styles in LIVEditor (which has a Firebug-like UI).

Answer (score 11):

If you want to override the css from here means, all you have to do is set `!important` to your css.

like `input.range{ width:73px !important}`

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I don't understand, I've followed your instructions, I change my rule to `input.range{
 width: 73px important! 
}` but it still not work :(

Comment: It's `!important` not `important!`.

Comment: Ah! Yes. I am sorry it is !important.. Thanks Peter O.

Answer (score 0):

The `width: 73px;`rule is overridden. As you see the `input.range` is defined in cramp.css. Above you should find a rule that overrides it.